# ES5 spec the Object type

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm reading through the ES5 spec and got a bit confused about the following piece:

> 8.6 The Object Type
>
> ... 
>   There are two kinds of access for named (non-internal) properties: get and put, corresponding to retrieval and assignment, respectively.

Can someone clarify what this phrase refers to exactly (what is its meaning?)? 
I have only seen the named accessor properties `get` and `set`.

Comment: It's internal. When you set a property a `put` operation is called. The ES 2015 spec no longer uses the term put.

Comment: @zeroflagL Ok, so I can assume that `put` is used in the same context as `set` here?

Comment: Yes. If you read on you'll find the description of the internal put method, that _"Sets the specified named property"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec is saying that *putting* and *getting* are two actions that can happen to properties. [Objects have the internal methods `[[Put]]` and `[[Get]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) that correspond to those actions.

[`[[Put]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.5) is an internal method, present within every object, that stores values in an object's properties. Any time you perform an assignment operation on a property, you cause the environment to perform a `[[Put]]`.

[`[[Set]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.1) is the internal property of an accessor property descriptor. This is what you define when you define a `set` setter function of an accessor property. (Note: `[[Set]]` exists on ***property descriptors***, not on objects. Not all properties have a `[[Set]]`, but all objects do have a `[[Put]]`.)

If you attempt to perform a `[[Put]]` on an object property which is an accessor property, that operation will invoke the property's `[[Set]]` function, per step 5 of the `[[Put]]` algorithm:

> 5. If IsAccessorDescriptor(desc) is true, then
>
>    - a. Let setter be desc.[[Set]] which cannot be undefined.
>    - b. Call the [[Call]] internal method of setter providing O as the this value and providing V as the sole argument.

In short, the function `[[Set]]` only applies to accessor properties, while `[[Put]` can apply to either accessor or data properties.

Comment: Ok, so they are not the same thing after all. Cool!

Comment: Got a bit confused about your phrase: If you attempt to perform a [[Put]] on an object property... I assume that you mean the runtime environment itself (we cannot access it directly?).

Comment: @KimGysen Yes, exactly. I just edited to be clearer, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

It's referring to the way you can access data, not function names. It's essentially explaining that ES5 objects can have properties accessed for writing, as in myObject.property = 5 and myObject['property'] = 5 or reading, in the analogous ways. It says "non-internal" because internal properties may only be put by the use of prototype.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this part. What I really wondered about is why they use `put` instead of `set`. Can I assume that they are used in the same context?

Comment: Probably the same thing, considering the context, as they are using a generic word (kind), and not using any markup.

Comment: What do you mean by your last sentence?

Comment: I meant that "kind" is an informal way of talking about the accessors. They do not have to be called that as the standard says that internal properties are not part of ES5.